# PostgreSQL: boolean column verify if condition true

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, boolean

I am going through some practice exercises and I am struggling with this one. Assume we have these two tables: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=62abf52cf7d9b2092636eabda8a7ef4f)

Tab1 stores the 'rev' based on the individual items in tab2. This means that (price x nr_items) for all items with status 's' (from tab2) should equal 'rev' from tab1. The task is to check if this is true or false and store the result in new boolean column 'ver'. the new column 'diff' computes the difference between (nr_items x price)-rev (in case there is a difference). In case there is no difference NULL should be returned, and not 0.
So far a managed to output the difference as 0 value but not NULL:

```
WITH t2 AS
    (SELECT id,
     or_id,
     dat,
    (SUM(nr_items * price) filter(WHERE status='s')) AS org_rev
    FROM tab2
    GROUP BY id, or_id, dat
    ORDER BY id, or_id)
SELECT t2.id,
     t2.or_id,
     t2.dat,
     ROUND((t2.org_rev - t1.rev)::numeric,0) AS diff     
FROM t2
JOIN tab1 t1
ON t2.dat = t1.dat AND t1.id=t2.id
GROUP BY t2.id, t2.or_id, t2.dat, t2.org_rev, t1.rev
```

But I have no idea how to get the boolean column. The output should look like this:
[image]

I hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: diff = 0 results in TRUE or FALSE, or NULL when diff is NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1b4bacc0e90d78fdf69fc5b929d61023)

```
SELECT
    t1.rev = ROUND(t2.org_rev::numeric, 2) as var,   -- 1
    NULLIF(                                          -- 2
        ROUND((t2.org_rev - t1.rev)::numeric,0)      -- your diff function
        , 0
    ) as diff
FROM ...
```

1. For `var` you need to add a simple comparision
2. For `diff` with nulls you can either use a `CASE` clause (`CASE WHEN value != 0 THEN value ELSE NULL END`) or the function `NULLIF()`